# How to retrieve a value from a stdClass Object?

Tags: stdclass

I have this class object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => success
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [network] => BTC
            [available_balance] => 0.00001
            [pending_received_balance] => 0.0
        )

)
```

How to get the value of only [available_balance]?

NB: im using php